# What is the type of mutablelistof(2, 'j') in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, types, integer, character

```
Fun main(){
    Val a = mutableListOf(2, 'j')
}
// What is the type of a?
```

i want to make it like this: val a = mutableListOf , but i dont the type

Answer (score 2):

Common supertypes of `Int` and `Char` are `Comparable<*>` and `Serializable`, so the type of `a` is:

- `MutableList<Comparable<*> & Serializable>`

Depending on what you will do with the resulting list (e.g. initialize a property, return from a function, etc.), some of the type information will be lost and the type will be "simplified" into:

- `MutableList<out Any>`

or:

- `MutableList<Any>`

Comment: It's actually inferred as the type `MutableList<Comparable<*>>` since that's the most specific common type. Not much more useful than Any, though, but there are cases where the distinction is important since the type is invariant.

Comment: Good point, do you think my updated answer is technically precise? @Tenfour04

Comment: Once the inferred type is assigned to a `val`, it's inferred type is not affected by downstream code. For example, given a function `fun foo(list: MutableList<Any>)`, you wouldn't be able to call `foo(a)` where `a` is the inferred result of `mutableListOf`. But if you directly pass the result of the `mutableListOf` function, it will infer it to match its destination type, such as `foo(mutableListOf(2, 'j')`.